# Converting DataFrame into sql

Tags: pandas, sqlite

I am using the following code to convert my pandas into sql, but I get the following error although my dtype is float64 for this particular column.

I have tried to convert my dtype to str, but this did not work.

```py
import sqlite3 
import pandas as pd 

#create db file
db = conn = sqlite3.connect(‘example.db’)
#convert my df data to sql
df = df(‘users’ , con=db, if_exists='replace')
```

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1214 - probably unsupported type.

However when I check the parameter 1214 i.e. column 1214 in my df. This col has a float64 dtype. I don't understand then how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your data types, as SQLite supports a limited number of data types --> https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. My guess would be to use a float dtype (so try dtype='float')

Comment: Thanks! The column that is giving the error has a float data type (dtype). I'm also kind of running to a different problem now. Trying to append new results from custom built functions to a DataFrame by using a for loop. However, using the same program code that I built months ago and used to work without any problems, it is now only saving the first row in the new data. I don't know what's going on there, but I am using Colab GPU. I will run basic examples and use old datasets to check where problem might be.